# Django migrations throw 1072 - key column 'car_make_id' doesn't exist in table

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-migrations

Here's simplified task and setup (Django 1.8, MySQL, Python 2.7), I've got:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    make = models.ForeignKey(CarMake)

class Bike(models.Model):
    make = models.ForeignKey(BikeMake)

class CarMake(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class BikeMake(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

Now, I need to ditch the **BikeMake** model completely so I update the **CarMake** model with values from **BikeMake** and also update the foreign key relationship in **Bike**.

I've created the following migration, which updates the **CarMake** with names from **BikeMake**, adds temporary field **Bike.car_make**, migrates data from **Bike.make** to **Bike.car_make**, removes the **Bike.make** field and renames **Bike.car_make** to **Bike.make**.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models, migrations


def update_car_makes(apps, schema_editor):
    """Update CarMakes with BikeMakes"""
    BikeMake = apps.get_model('my_app', 'BikeMake')
    CarMake = apps.get_model('my_app', 'CarMake')

    for item in BikeMake.objects.all():
        if not CarMake.objects.filter(name=item.name).exists():
            CarMake.objects.create(name=item.name)


def remove_car_makers(apps, schema_editor):
    """Restore original CarMake (exclude BikeMake)"""
    pass


def migrate_to_car_make(apps, schema_editor):
    """Set Bike.car_make according to Bike.make"""
    CarMake = apps.get_model('my_app', 'CarMake')
    Bike = apps.get_model('my_app', 'Bike')
    for item in Bike.objects.all():
        old_make = item.make
        new_make = CarMake.objects.get(name=old_make.name)
        item.car_make = new_make
        item.save()


def reverse_migrate_to_car_make(apps, schema_editor):
    pass


def dummy_forwards(apps, schema_editor):
    # Empty forward migration needed for having custom backwards migration
    pass


def restore_make_column_data(apps, schema_editor):
    BikeMake = apps.get_model('products', 'BikeMake')
    Bike = apps.get_model('products', 'Bike')

    for item in Bike.objects.all():
        old_make = item.bike_make
        new_make = BikeMake.objects.get(name=old_make.name)
        item.make = new_make
        item.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [('my_app', '0001_blah_blah')]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(
            update_car_makers,
            reverse_code=remove_car_makers
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='bike',
            name='car_make',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default=1, to='my_app.CarMake'),
            preserve_default=False
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(
            migrate_to_car_make,
            reverse_code=reverse_migrate_to_car_make
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(
            dummy_forwards,
            reverse_code=restore_make_column_data
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='bike',
            name='make',
        ),
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='bike',
            old_name='car_make',
            new_name='make'
        )
    ]
```

And when I try to run it, I get the #1072 error on running the last operation: `migrations.RenameField`. Now the interesting part is that from DB POV everything is complete, data migrated, column renamed, only the migration isn't marked as done and error is thrown.

Also if I just move the `migrations.RenameField` to a separate migration file and run two migrations in a row – everything works fine and it doesn't raise the #1072 error.

In addition, I've tried inserting a breakpoint just before the `migrations.RenameField` and I verified that **Bike.car_make** column exists and I can fetch normally all objects of **Bike** model at that point.

The MySQL query, that results in error is following:

```
CREATE INDEX `my_app_bike_c2036163` ON `my_app_bike` (`car_make_id`)
```

Any ideas how to fix it and have it within one migration file? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 04.02.16**

As @kvikshaug pointed out, this happens because Django creates indexes and constraints after performing all operations i.e. raw SQL for creating index and/or constraints is generated at the time, the corresponding operation is executed (in my case `AddField`), but that query is actually run at the very end, thus the error.

One possible solution for relatively small schemas could be to use Django's [`RunSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) and type the raw queries yourself, but that's quite cumbersome + you've got to create constraints yourself.

So I went with separating the renaming migration.

Comment: I think you might be trying to do too much work in one migration. I think you might be better with several migrations e.g. 1. Create the new field `car_make`. 2. Populate the `car_make` field. 3. Remove the old `make` field 4. Rename the `car_make` field to `make`.

Comment: Might be so, but even if I end up separating those actions to several migrations, I'd still like to know, why do I get the error.

Answer (score 2):

Django migrations create indexes after performing all operations. Your second operation, adding field `car_make`, makes Django add the `CREATE INDEX` command which you noted causes the error:

```
CREATE INDEX `my_app_bike_c2036163` ON `my_app_bike` (`car_make_id`)
```

**Even though you later renamed the field, Django still tries to create the index for the now-missing `car_make` field, that's why you get the error.** You can see this clearly by running `sqlmigrate`:

```
$ ./manage.py sqlmigrate my_app 0002_blah_blah
BEGIN;
--
-- MIGRATION NOW PERFORMS OPERATION THAT CANNOT BE WRITTEN AS SQL:
-- Raw Python operation
--
--
-- Add field car_make to bike
--
ALTER TABLE "my_app_bike" ADD COLUMN "car_make_id" integer DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE "my_app_bike" ALTER COLUMN "car_make_id" DROP DEFAULT;
--
-- MIGRATION NOW PERFORMS OPERATION THAT CANNOT BE WRITTEN AS SQL:
-- Raw Python operation
--
--
-- MIGRATION NOW PERFORMS OPERATION THAT CANNOT BE WRITTEN AS SQL:
-- Raw Python operation
--
--
-- Remove field make from bike
--
ALTER TABLE "my_app_bike" DROP CONSTRAINT "my_app_bike_make_id_5615ed11_fk_my_app_bikemake_id";
ALTER TABLE "my_app_bike" DROP COLUMN "make_id" CASCADE;
--
-- Rename field car_make on bike to make
--
ALTER TABLE "my_app_bike" RENAME COLUMN "car_make_id" TO "make_id";
CREATE INDEX "my_app_bike_78e8ca60" ON "my_app_bike" ("car_make_id");
ALTER TABLE "my_app_bike" ADD CONSTRAINT "my_app_bike_car_make_id_6c42be09_fk_my_app_carmake_id" FOREIGN KEY ("car_make_id") REFERENCES "my_app_carmake" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;

COMMIT;
```

You could try to report this as a bug (or search; maybe it's already reported), but you're probably best off following Alasdairs suggestion and just separate the migrations.